# Dynamic SELECT checking for records with apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I use this simple select statement, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM @table
WHERE [A] LIKE '%&%' OR 
[A] LIKE '%''%'
```

But I get an error if I try:

```
DECLARE @SourceTable nvarchar(50) = '@table',
@ColumnName nvarchar(50) = 'A'

EXEC('SELECT * FROM '+ @SourceTable +
' WHERE ['+ @ColumnName + '] LIKE ''%&%'' OR ['+
@ColumnName + '] LIKE ''%''%''')
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '%'.
```

Comment: Put 4 single quotes between the % signs.

Comment: @TabAlleman Correct. You should have posted this as the answer.

Comment: @Christa you doubled the apostrophes outside of the percent signs, though you forgot the do the same between the percent signs - hence the comment by Tab

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks! I thought I tried it before, but I guess I didn't!

Comment: @Eli true, but I wanted to check for duplicates first.